# PHP: How to get type of variable from an input field

Tags: php, variables, types

I need answer for this type of question. Please I need to get type of variable from HTML input field and to echo that type of $var.

From this form I need to check what type of data is entered. Is it string or integer, etc.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="podatak" value="podatak" />
<input type="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not know what input/select/textarea type you got.

Comment: @user1677402 See my edit to the answer, that's probably what I would go with.

Answer (score 7):

All form submimssions are strings to begin with as such. You can however use functions like [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to see if the item is a number and [is_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) to see if the form element being passed is an array (ie, checkboxes, possibly files and the like).

Based on your comments, I would do something like the following:

```
function whatTypeAmI($var)
{
    if(is_array($var)
    {
        // Request is likely a checkbox or multiple files.
        echo "I am an Array! Yeeehaaa!";
    }
    else if(is_numeric($var))
    {
        // I look like a number, or someone 
        // typed in a number into a text field.
        echo "I am a Fluffeh number!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Goodness, who knows what on earth happened?";
    }
}

foreach($_POST as $val)
{
    whatTypeAmI($val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's always a string or an array. If `is_array($_POST['value'])` returns true; it's an array. In any other case it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are trying to find form field type not the data type... like text, submit, button etc... if that is your scenario then i am afraid there is not such function. As far as i know form post will not send any form type information to the server... any way you can do it using associative array. ex: on your php side do some thing like.

```
<?php 
     function getType($elementName){
         $formType = array('elementName1' => 'elementType1', 'elementName2' => 'elementType2'......); 
         if(array_key_exists($elementName, $formType))
             return $formType[$elementName];
         return 'Unknown';
     }

     foreach($_POST AS $elementName => $elementVal){
          echo 'name = '.$elementName.' type = '. getType($elementName).' value ='.$elementVal;
     }
```

Comment: I need a type of the input data, is it a integer or string. I need to enter something in the input field and to echo type of that input data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var_dump($variable)`.

Answer (score -1):

you can make use of these functions :  `is_int` , `is_array` , `is_null`, `is_float` , `is_double` , `is_bool`, etc.

Comment: But will it not always be a string or array?

Comment: then, use other methods, such as is_null, is_float, is_double, etc ?

Comment: It will still be only a string or an array.

Comment: or `null` if the input field does not exist .

Comment: In that case it won't be defined, not null.

Answer (score -2):

```
function gettype_custom($var){
    if(is_array($var)){
        return 'array';
    }elseif(is_numeric($var)){
        return 'numeric';
    }elseif(is_string($var)){
        return 'string';
    }else{
        return 'unknown';
    }
}
```

Comment: Not my down-vote, but I'm guessing you got Down-voted because `$_POST` or `$_GET` data is either an array or a string. `gettype` is therefore not useful in this case

Comment: but how to connect it with this:

<form action="page.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="podatak" value="<?php $var ?>" />
<input type="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>

Comment: `<input type="text" name="podatak" value="<?php echo $var; ?>" />`